# Widget Option is Missing

Tags: theme-development, customization, themes, widgets

My Widget Option is missing in the Dashboard area. How can i make that appear? 
I have downloaded this Blank Theme from Chris Coyiers [site](http://html5reset.org/#wordpress).

sidebar.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage HTML5-Reset-WordPress-Theme
 * @since HTML5 Reset 2.0
 */
?>

<div class="sidebar">
  <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && !dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar Widgets')) : else : ?>

  <!-- All this stuff in here only shows up if you DON'T have any widgets active in this zone -->

  <?php get_search_form(); ?>
  <h3>
    <?php _e('Archives','html5reset'); ?>
  </h3>
  <ul>
    <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
  </ul>
  <h3>
    <?php _e('Meta','html5reset'); ?>
  </h3>
  <ul>
    <?php wp_register(); ?>
    <li>
      <?php wp_loginout(); ?>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://wordpress.org/" title="<?php _e('Powered by WordPress, state-of-the-art semantic personal publishing platform.','html5reset'); ?>">
      <?php _e('WordPress','html5reset'); ?>
      </a></li>
    <?php wp_meta(); ?>
  </ul>
  <h3>
    <?php _e('Subscribe','html5reset'); ?>
  </h3>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>">
      <?php _e('Entries (RSS)','html5reset'); ?>
      </a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('comments_rss2_url'); ?>">
      <?php _e('Comments (RSS)','html5reset'); ?>
      </a></li>
  </ul>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

the widget code in my functions.php

```
// Widgets
if ( !function_exists('register_sidebar' )) {
    function html5reset_widgets_init() {
        register_sidebar( array(
            'name'          => __( 'Sidebar Widgets', 'html5reset' ),
            'id'            => 'sidebar-primary',
            'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
            'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h2>',
        ) );
    }
    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'html5reset_widgets_init' );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Put this lines of code in function.php

```
if (function_exists("register_sidebar")) {
register_sidebar();
}
```

Put this to sidebar.php

```
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar() ) : ?>
<?php $image = new WP_query ('showposts=1');
if(have_posts()) : while($image->have_posts()) : $image->the_post; ?>

  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to 
 <?php  the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php postimage(); ?></a>

 <?php endwhile; endif; rewind_posts; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I replaced this

```
// Widgets
if ( !function_exists('register_sidebar' )) {
function html5reset_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Sidebar Widgets', 'html5reset' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-primary',
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'html5reset_widgets_init' );
```

}

into this ..

```
// Widgets
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Sidebar Widgets',
        'id'   => 'sidebar-widgets',
        'description'   => 'These are widgets for the sidebar.',
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2>',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>'
    ));
}
```

Then the widget option came out..